# Circuit designing?

Tags: electrical-engineering

How doe one design a circuit.  I know all the components but don't know where to place the components. It would be really helpful if one can explain a simple complex rc circuit. How does the current flow and why the components are there.i am trying to learn by example.

Comment: Simple complex?

Comment: Firs,. learn to *analyse* circuits. I mean analyse them by hand, don't blindly use a simulator and hope you didn't make any mistakes! If you think "hand analysis" involves too much calculation to be practical, *you are doing it wrong* because you don't really understand the circuit yet! Then, look at circuits other people have designed and figure out for yourself how they work. Then, start designing your own circuits.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of MultiSim. It's an electronic schematic capture and simulation program which is part of a suite of circuit design programs.

It will give you a great idea on where to place everything and you can even test it out in a simulation, to make sure everything will work out!

A simple complex circuit seems contradictory, but I have completed rc circuit setups and you need, obviously a resistor, capacitor, circuit board to set up everything on it, circuit cables to connect everything together, and a power source.

The current flows from the positive terminal of the power source, towards the rest of the components, to finally come back to the negative terminal of the power source.

Comment: Never been a big fan of Multisim. It has an extremely large amount of bugs. For instance, there are some FET parameters that get completely neglected.

Comment: That being said. I would highly recommend LTSpice over Multisim any day.

Comment: @KingDuken Never heard of LTSpice but I will definitely check it out myself! Thank you, also Arduino board and the coding would be a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

A simple place to start is to find a Radio Shack that is still open and purchase a breadboard and some simple arduino circuit boards, then just experiment. There are loads of examples with devices made with arduino components and custom circuit boards made using bread boards.

https://www.ebay.com/p/?iid=261740468056&lpid=82&&&ul_noapp=true&chn=ps

Comment: Looks like the link is redundant